# What is the name for the term that describes small changes in normality?

Tags: terminology

Small changes can be very difficult for humans to recognise, so we get used to the new normal and do not realise that the many small changes have collectively created a huge change.

To take one specific example of this phenomenon, lifestyle creep means that as a person earns more, they spend more, as their "normal" has changed.

What is the general term for this changing normal baseline?

Comment: If it's a gradual worsening, this is the _slippery slope_, essentially already covered on ELU. A gradual improvement? There are no reasonable suggestions in another thread ([Is there any expression that is the opposite of 'slippery slope'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92000/is-there-any-expression-that-is-the-opposite-of-slippery-slope/92018#92018))

Comment: Well, I think originally this creep business started with desert creep. But anything can "creep" in that sense.

Comment: @Lambie - Dessert crêpes? Count me in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some situations this is slangily called "[*frog boiling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling_frog)", after the trope that a frog won't notice it if you place it gradually warming water, until suddenly (it seems) it's too hot to tolerate.

Comment: It's closer than the other answers, but I'm not sure how idiomatic the expression itself is.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I've used it myself in reference to developing cataracts. You don't notice it happening, but when they're gone... wow. You might hear it in semi-inverted form as 'boiling a frog'

Comment: 40 000 hits on Google, with some decent examples, deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The first term to pop into my mind is *[gradation](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/gradations)*:

> A series of gradual, successive stages or degrees: the gradation of ranks in the army. One of these stages or degrees: social gradations. A gradual or barely perceptible change from one tone or shade, as of color, to another.

An example sentence:

> The gradations in his upward mobility were scarcely recognized because they were so gradual.

Comment: Google search:  _No results found for "gradations in his upward mobility"._ I think the sentence sounds unnatural.

Comment: gradations in upward mobility could  be measurements levels on a chart. But doesn't really work with "his".

Answer (score 0):

**adjustment**

> The act or process of adjusting
>
> **adjust** (intransitive v.)   To adapt or conform oneself (as to new
> conditions) [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adjusting)

> The process of adapting or becoming used to a new situation.
>
> *For many couples there may need to be a period of adjustment*
>
> *The characters lives and experiences demonstrate their displacement, spiritual homelessness, and the hardships of adjustment to a new
> society.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/adjustment?locale=en)

---

> There are other times in life that often demand radical **adjustment** to
> a *new  normal* such as:
>
> Divorce—This is a *new normal*
> ....
> Health crisis—This is a *new
> normal* ... [P. J. Flamming; *Never Stop Starting*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Never_Stop_Starting/yDsyDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22adjustment%20to%20a%20new%20normal%22&pg=PT105&printsec=frontcover)

> And we saw how at some point those prophets and social critics forced
> a change in race relations and an **adjustment** to a new normal. [K.
> B. Bedell; *Realizing the Civil Rights Dream*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Realizing_the_Civil_Rights_Dream_Diagnos/L5AwDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22adjustment%20to%20a%20new%20normal%22&pg=PA87&printsec=frontcover)

> Americans began the uneasy **adjustment** to a new normal. The effort
> to stop thieves from stealing cars was never the main objective of the
> changes that created "fortress American," but it was a bellwether. [J.
> A. Heitmann and R. H. Morales; *Stealing Cars*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Stealing_Cars/yK8AAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22adjustment%20to%20a%20new%20normal%22&pg=PA69&printsec=frontcover)